# IOS::Revmob ads integrating into our Project

Tags: objective-c, revmobads

When I click the RevMob ad banner I get the following screen. Does it mean it is working or not?

In Dashboard I generated with "On With Ads".

I have written this code for RevmobAds:::

```
[RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"54b9fdbcf47abad967fa6530"];
 [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you just contact RevMob directly? By the way the screenshot is self-explanatory: "Test successful" means all is going well.

Comment: Thanks for replaying and edited my post.What we have to write for that.

Comment: Just send them over the link of this question or copy/paste the text of the question. By the way, it would be just a waste of time. "Test successful" means the code is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is working. "Test successful" means the code you have written is correct. If you still need more details, contact them directly.